# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, cors, angular7

I've a problem when I try to do PATCH request in an angular 7 web application.
In my backend I have:

```typescript
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.set({
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'",
    });

    next();
});
```

In my frontend service, I've:

```typescript
  patchEntity(ent: any, id) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': '*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.patch('my_url', ent).map((res: Response) => res.json());
  };
```

The error is:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'my_url' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

What can I to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check)

Comment: Wildcard for `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` is not yet supported in all browsers. Also that error message says it came back with a non-200 status, so you should see why it's erroring first

Comment: @user184994 thank you, is there a different method instead Access-Control-Allow-Methods?

Comment: No, just pass the actual values, so `POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH` plus any others you care about

Comment: Please refer to this post for answer nd how to solve this problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528643/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-angular-or-angular-6-problem-while-you/53528644#53528644

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node JS - CORS Issue Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736327/node-js-cors-issue-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-c)

Comment: The answer section is slowly filling up with tips about how to break/disable CORS on your favorite server, which is not a very smart thing to do in general, and quite off-topic in the context of this question as well. Marked question as 'Protected'.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There are two ways this can be handled:

1. Temporary Front-End solution so you can test if your API integration is working:

Click on window -> type run and hit enter -> in the command window copy:

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

This will open a new "Chrome" window where you can work easily. This is a temporary solution. Every time you will have to work with this chrome window.

2. Permanent solution:

In the backend code, the developer needs to add an annotation @Crossorigin right above the CRUD api call method.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: First Temporary Front-End solution is working fine but second backend solution not working as expected

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same issue and the permanent solution is not working for me.

Comment: Somewho knows the temporary solution command for mac?

Answer (score 11):

Your error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at `'my_url'` from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

My error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at `'localhost:3000/api/todo'` from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

(Even though a bit different error but i'll answer anyway)

Now two questions here:

1. How did i resolve my issue?

> Ans. Putting 'http://' before api i used, means 'http://localhost:3000/api/todo'.

2. What might've caused your error?

> Ans. Can't say for sure but i dont see your api url instead it says 'my_url' (comparing both errors). I thik you may've passed string instead of variable.

I'll be happy if this helps anyone. Because this cost me almost 2hr and now it's midnight(almost).

Comment: `http://` prefix solved it for me in a tenant solution.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue even though my API was using cors and had the proper headers.

So for me, the issue was that I was making an insecure request. I was accessing my API over the **http** protocol, and that was causing the error.

I just changed from

```
http://api.example.com
```

to **https** protocol

```
https://api.example.com
```

and it fixed everything.

---

You can also create a simple proxy on your website to forward your request to the external site. For example, if you are trying to fetch some data from your website (**my-website.com**) to (**another-website.com**) and you make a POST request, you can have cors issues, but if you fetch the data from your own domain you will be good.

Here is how to create a simple proxy forwarding the request https://stackoverflow.com/a/20354642/7602110

So instead of making request to

```
POST https://api.example.com/event/create
```

You'll want to make the request to

```
POST https://my-website.com/api/event/create
```

I know that is some extra work, and sometimes you don't have the ability to do it, but that will definitely prevent you from having cors issues.

Answer (score 7):

use this in Node

```js
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    //Enabling CORS
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, 
    Accept, x-client-key, x-client-token, x-client-secret, Authorization");
      next();
    });
```

And in angular the request is

```
 auth(login): Promise<any> {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   this._http.post('url:3000/api/auth/login', { ...login })
     .subscribe((response: any) => {
       resolve(response);
     });
 });
}
```

Comment: That won't help. Nothing there will make the OPTIONS request has a 200 OK response.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is not on your frontend angular code it is related to backend,

Try below steps in your backend code :

1.`npm install cors`

2.put `app.use(cors())` in main express route file.(enables all CORS requests)

may be it works for you.

reference link : https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Comment: That's insufficient. See https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: It works for me, do not forget to add const cors = require('cors')

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue some time ago. Below piece of code worked for me at the backend. The backend was written in express, node.

```
app.use(function (request, response, next) {
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: That won't help. Nothing there will make the OPTIONS request has a 200 OK response.

Answer (score 1):

### Firebase server specific issue:

In my case, I got the same below error while I am trying to access my URL.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://XXX-XXX-XXX-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

The code I used to send this request is below,

```
this.http
      .put(
        "https://XXX-XXX-XXX-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/",
        data
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

---

I tried searching for a solution to my issue and couldn't find the exact solution. Anyhow I managed to figure out my mistake and here is my solution.

For my case, the error is due to invalid URL. I am supposed to send with a `.json` at the end of URL for firebase to consider it as a valid URL. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start)

After appending `.json` to my URL, my http requests got success.

```
this.http
      .put(
        "https://XXX-XXX-XXX-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/.json",
        data
      )
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding proxy in package.json or bypassing with chrome extension is not really a solution. Just make sure you've enabled CORS in your server side before you have registered your routes. Given example is in Node.js and Express.js. Hope this helps!

```
app.use(cors())
app.use('/posts', postRoutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

for those who using ASP.net Core in the Backend

ADD this to program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddCors(c =>
{
    c.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin", options => options.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().
     AllowAnyHeader());
});

app.UseCors("AllowOrigin");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was due to a missing '/' in service.ts. I was using Django for the backend.

```
getData(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.APIurl}/data/${id}`);
}
```

So, I added a '/' at the end.

```
getData(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.APIurl}/data/${id}/`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use this header at the bottom of ".htaccess":

```
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://example.com"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type,Authorization, Accept"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Tomcat try this: [full documentation](https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html)

```
 HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, "
                + "Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");


        if ( request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
            return;
        }


        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
```

Then in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <filter-class>classYouImplementTheCodeAbove</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cors</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If you are using other
go to https://enable-cors.org/server.html
and search for it

Comment: "If you are using Tomcat" — They aren't.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issues and it was an syntax error in my action definition

```
 def self.rate_skills(params)
    data = {}
    data = where(individual_id: params[:individual_id]).select(:tool_name, :score)group('category').order(score: :desc).first(3)
    data 
  end
```

the issue is that I was the period before "group"

```
 def self.rate_skills(params)
    data = {}
    data = where(individual_id: params[:individual_id]).select(:tool_name, :score).group('category').order(score: :desc).first(3)
    data 
  end
```

Comment: this was on a ruby on rails back end web app