# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://site.local/api/v1/profiles' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: angular, laravel, cross-domain, policy

I've a problem when I try to get data from this endpoint `http://cappoffshore.ms.local/api/v1/profiles` (virtual host). But it working when I used this endpoint `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/profiles` (got it via `php artisan serve`).

I tried many solution like:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check#35588856](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588699/response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check#35588856)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/53528643/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-angular-or-angular-6-problem-while-you/53528644#53528644](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528643/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-in-angular-or-angular-6-problem-while-you/53528644#53528644)

But that still not working for me.

This is what I got for those endpoint :

using `http://localhost:8000`

[image]

using  `http://cappoffshore.ms.local` virtual host:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I run into this problem many times. CORS policy is a delicated issue.

I always install in my projects this package via composer.

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

In Laravel you allow to receive request from different domains with this package. Maybe it is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @Antobla, Thank yous, But still not working I gote the same error

Comment: @MalkiMohamed could you try to make the request via Postman? It is strange that status code "301"

Comment: @Antobla, from postman it works fine, I think its something related with a virtual host, this is how I create it
`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/PATH_TO_PROJECT_FOLDER/public"
    ServerName cappoffshore.ms.local
</VirtualHost>`