# Why is Safari sometimes, but not always, throwing a cors error when posting to my nodejs API?

Tags: node.js, macos, safari, cors

I am working as part of a team to design a website where users can either upload an existing video, or record a new video file in-browser. Selecting a file for upload is done with a standard html form, while recording uses react-video-recorder. In either case, once the file is ready, the form is submitted using a ky post request.

```
const response = await ky.post(`https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/upload`,
        {
          timeout: false,
          body: formData, 
          
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem('token')}`
          }
        }).json();
```

Both methods of adding a file go through this same function, so the headers on the post request will be literally the same regardless of how the user added their video.

Despite this, Safari will throw a cors error *only* when attempting to upload a video recorded with react-video-recorder. This does not occur when attempting to record and post a video using Chrome for Mac on the same page.

I have checked on the server side, and I am specifically setting the headers to allow the site - I even tried literally copying the "origin" header of the request into the value for "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", just in case I'd made a typo

```
app.post('/upload', 
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}),
    function(req,res) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','https://my-website.com')
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','POST, GET, OPTIONS')
        ...
```

At this point, I'm wondering if it's actually a cors issue at all, or if there's something else messed up and Safari is just giving me profoundly unhelpful error messages while I'm troubleshooting. Does anyone have any ideas or tips they can give me?

EDIT: I was able to copy the contents of the http requests, and they are different - I just don't know why...

The successful request is:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Origin: https://my-website.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryGRcSY52tKpQVBLIb
Authorization: Bearer _redacted
Referer: https://my-website.com/
Content-Length: 51199
Host: my-api.com:3004
Accept-Language: en-ca
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

The failed request:

```
POST /upload
Authorization: Bearer _redacted
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary0Uzp1dEaDyHuIhEw
Accept: application/json
Origin: https://my-website.com
Referer: https://my-website.com/Upload
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.2 Safari/605.1.15
```

Does this indicate that the video file wasn't successfully attached to the post request?

Comment: Probably you are sometimes triggering the browser to pre-flight the request and your server does not handle the OPTIONS request that is involved in browser pre-flight.  See this page on pre-flighted request [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) for details.  There are very specific things that trigger a pre-flight.  Even just a different content-type can trigger the pre-flight.  The browser console probably contains more details about exactly what is happening and why.  If it is sending a pre-flight request, that will show in the network tab.

Comment: I just attempted this, modifying my routes to specifically enable CORS preflight as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44736327/node-js-cors-issue-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-c

It did not work, and even if I did it wrong I don't think it's the issue. Looking at my server traffic, all of my post requests were already making preflight checks, including all the successful ones in Chrome, Firefox, etc. It only fails when attempting to go perform that one task in Safari specifically

Comment: I don't know Safari, but does it have the equivalent of Chrome's network tab that shows you exactly what the browser is sending to the server and getting back from the server?  Usually, that tells the story.  Otherwise, you need to instrument your server and see exactly what it is getting from Safari.  This is just a standard debugging challenge where you have to open the black box and see exactly what is being sent both ways and then use that as your main clue as to where to look next or how to fix.

Comment: Also, what is `ky.post()`?  What library is that?

Comment: ky is a simple library for making fetch requests easier - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ky